# Can sublime wrap all code into view so I don't have to horizontally scroll?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have longer lines of text (separated by spaces...no long single word) that veer off to the right side of the editor. The only way I can read them is if I scroll horizontally. Is there a way to wrap all the text that falls out of view on the right? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

Go to preferences > settings - user 
and add:

`"word_wrap": true`

Then save the file and restart sublime